# Google Tag Manager - Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Currently, the implementation of Universal Analytics in GTM does not allow for ability to edit the HTML scripts - for ability to change code to capture Demographic and Interest level data.  Has anyone figured out how to adjust the scripts (necessary to change the script) to be able to capture the Demographic and Interest level data from the Google Display Network?

Answer (score 4):

Universal Analytics doesn't support Demographic and Interest level data yet. There is more information on this on the [Universal Analytics Upgrade Center - Upgrade Center](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/guide#consider-this) - take a look at the Important Considerations section regarding **Data integrations related to dc.js JavaScript Library aren't supported, but are coming soon.**

"The dc.js JavaScript library isn’t supported in Universal Analytics, but will be in the coming year. If you rely on dc.js related features, such as Remarketing, Google Display Network Impression Reporting, DoubleClick Campaign Manager Integration, or Google Analytics Demographics and Interests Reports, do not upgrade to Universal Analytics yet. Wait until you see an announcement about dc.js in Universal Analytics, and upgrade then."

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this question and is still wondering, this integration is now available via Google Tag Manager for any Universal Analytics tags.

From a technical perspective, all you need to do is tick the checkbox for **Enable Display Advertising Features** when creating your Universal Analytics tag.

Note that it's likely you will need to make changes to your website's privacy policy before you can use this feature.

[Display Advertising features](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3450482)

[Policy requirements for Google Analytics Advertising Features](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2700409)