# I cannot get the Google AdWords Remarketing tag to work

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get Google remarketing working on a site that has Google Analytics and AdWords.

AdWords does not recognize the Javascript remarketing tag on the site.

I am using Google Tag Manager. Tag manager contains tags for Universal Analytics, AdWords Remarketing and a custom HTML tag containing the JS code for Google Translate.

I've verified that the tag is working in three ways:

- Tag Manager in debug mode indicates that the remarketing tag is firing.
- A request is being made to googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/. Response is 302.  (https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/verification)
- Google Tag Assistant reports that Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager and Remarketing Tag are all "working". Tag assistant doesn't report the translation tag but translation is working correctly.

The AdWords account is linked to the Analytics account.

In AdWords / Shared Library / Audiences / View it still says "We haven't detected the Google Analytics remarketing functionality on your website".  I've waited several days.

A related problem is that in Analytics / Property / Remarketing / Audiences, my audience lists are empty, even the system-defined "All visitors". I think that is because the remarketing tag is not working. Analytics reports about 1300 users per week which I think is enough to start building an audience list.

I tried it earlier without using Tag Manager and it still didn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Have you verified all of the IDs in the tag are correct?  AdWords and Analytics generate separate lists so they are not related here (although you can push your analytics audiences to AdWords).  If you can post your URL it will be easier to check!

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the "Enable Display Advertising Features" checkbox on the Universal Analytics tag on GTM? This suppose to support the remarketing tag via Google Analytics, otherwise your remarketing tag should be handled via Adwords

Comment: There's really nothing to show. If I edit that tag in GTM, it's all defaults. I just added a name ("AdWords Remarketing") and entered my Conversion ID. The tag type is "AdWords Remarketing". Custom parameters is set to "Use Data Layer" and nothing is set in "Advanced Settings". That total describes the setup in GTM.

Comment: In the screenshot I'll be able to see whether you set the firing rules correctly.

Comment: Analytics and Remarketing tags are set to fire on "All Pages". I forgot to mention that but it's been set like that from the beginning. {{url}} matches RegEx .* as generated by the system when I selected "all pages". There are no blocking rules. They are firing as verified by the three methods I listed.

Comment: Did you check the "Enable Display Advertising Features" checkbox on the Universal Analytics tag on GTM? This suppose to support the remarketing tag via Google Analytics, otherwise your remarketing tag should be handled via Adwords - you should have an All Visitors group. But from your question it seems that you did not check it?

Comment: No that was not on but I have now turned it on. Thanks. I'll see what happens in the next day or so. It's all a bit confusing as to what does what. The AdWords and Analytics accounts are linked. I think that's what makes the user list generated by Analytics available in AdWords.

Comment: My audience list in Analytics (and visible in AdWords) finally has some members. That "Display Advertising features" was my main problem. AdWords still says it can't detect the Analytics remarketing tag but I've found on another forum, someone saying that it always says that if the tag is delivered via GTM. I haven't been able to confirm that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107124?hl=en and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892663/google-tag-manager-universal-analytics and https://www.quora.com/Why-isnt-Google-Analytics-validating-my-demographics-tracking-code-through-Google-Tag-Manager were helpful to me. Google Adwords says there is often an 18+ hour delay in their site updating. I waited a couple days and saw that it finally started working.